# If Jquery variable equals the class of a div then set display to block

Tags: php, jquery

I'm outputting several divs using php - each div has a different country name for the class.

I'm also outputting a variable using jquery which checks if content of a div has changed. That variable will also be a country name.

If the jquery variable matches a div class, I want that div to `.show()`, how can I do that?

This is my (horrible) attempt:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#block1").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
            message = $("#block1").html();
            regiondiv = '.';
            fullregion = regiondiv + message;
            alert(fullregion);

            if ($('.region-logos').hasClass(message)) {
                $(fullregion).show();
            } else {
                $(fullregion).hide();   
            }

        });
    });                             
})(jQuery);
```

If I click on Canada for instance, it will show the `.Canada` div, but if I click on Spain after it, it's shows the `.Spain` div as well as the `.Canada` div. I.e once you click on more than one it just continues to show them all. It doesn't hide the divs if you haven't click on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var class = 'no-class';     
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#block1").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
       var regiondiv = '.';
       var fullregion = regiondiv + class ;
       $(".fullregion").hide();
       class = $("#block1").html();
       fullregion = regiondiv + class ;
       $(".fullregion").show();
    });   
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question with more of an attempt. It's not hiding the divs that don't match the variable.

Comment: Yes something like that. Perhaps hide all first then show the right div?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I followed the question correctly. I assume you want to display a div if class of that div matches a variable in javascript. If so the you can try this:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("body").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
            // Not sure how are you generating this jquery variable
            var yourJqueryVariable;
            // Check if class name exists
            if ($(".yourJqueryVariable")[0]){
               $(".yourJqueryVariable").show(); //or even $(".yourJqueryVariable").css('display','block');
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question with more of an attempt. It's not hiding the divs that don't match the variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#block1").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
            var message = $("#block1").html();

            //ok so you have the variable to check 
            if($('.'+message).length > )) { //is there 1 or more of these classes in the DOM?
                $('.'+message).each(function() { //there is, loop and show them all 
                    $(this).show();  
                }); 
            }

        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**EDIT**

Ok looking at your updated answer, assuming there are multiple `.region-logos` you need to perform your if else within a loop of those:

```
$('.region-logos').each(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass(message)) {
       $(fullregion).show();
    }else {
       $(fullregion).hide();
    } 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question with more of an attempt. It's not hiding the divs that don't match the variable.

Comment: @Rob Hey I've edited my answer, let me know how it goes